# NodeJS user authentication with JWT

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am just started with nodejs with react frontend. But I have some issue while authenticating user. I am trying to fetch user with specific email and password. My api for this is as follows:
I have created three files controller, services and router files for any api request.

```
//userServices.js
const db = require('./../../db-connection/connection')

userAuth: (params, callback) => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = ?`,[params.email],
      (error, result, fields) => {
        if(!error) {
          console.log('result = ' + result[0]);
          return callback(error, result[0])
        }
        else
          return callback(error)
      });
  }
```

And this is my userController js file.

```
//userController.js
const {create, userindex, userAuth} = require('./UserServices');
const {genSaltSync, hashSync, compareSync} = require('bcrypt');
const {sign} = require('jsonwebtoken');

userLoginAuth: (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    userAuth(body, (error, results) => {
      if (error)
        console.log(error);

      if (!results) {
        return res.json({
          success: 0,
          data: 'Invalid email or password'
        })
      }

      const result = compareSync(body.password, results.password);
      if(!result) {
        results.password = undefined;
        const jsontoken = sign({result: results}, 'choegyel123', {
          expiresIn: '1h'
        });
        return res.json({
          success: 1,
          message: 'Login successful',
          token: jsontoken
        })
      } else
        console.log('password' + result.password)
      return res.json({
        success: 0,
        error: 'Invalid email or password'
      });
    });
  }
```

But the problem is in userServices.js file. My sql query is correctly executed but in callback for the ' results ' i am getting weird object. I think I should get some array of corresponding data from the database table and in my console log I am getting [object object]. I am not sure what does this actually mean and I am also all sure this is a blocker, since I cannot retrive password with this object in my userController. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do not concatenate the log message but give separate objects. "console.log('password', result.password)". Comma instead of plus. This does not solve your main problem, but shows you what result.password actually is

Comment: What do you get when you do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(result[0]));`?

Comment: @c_froehlich: it says, 'password' undefined

Comment: then check result: console.log(result)

Answer (score 0):

**Issues**

- `compareSync` returns a boolean with `true` indicating correct password. You're using `if(!result)` which is the reverse.
- Make sure your `{}` are correct on the `else`
- You're logging `result.password` which is `undefined` because `result` is your compareSync return value. You meant to log `results.password`. Avoid using `result` and `results` for two different things because it makes it easy to make these mistakes. Something like `bcryptResult` and `resultObj` might be better.
- When you `console.log()`, pass data as the second argument or make a second log because concatenating objects always shows `[object Object]`.

**Updated snippet**

```
  const result = compareSync(body.password, results.password);
  if(result) {
    results.password = undefined;
    const jsontoken = sign({result: results}, 'choegyel123', {
      expiresIn: '1h'
    });
    return res.json({
      success: 1,
      message: 'Login successful',
      token: jsontoken
    })
  } else {
    console.log('password', results.password)
    return res.json({
      success: 0,
      error: 'Invalid email or password'
    });
  }
```